# How does gradient update work in SimOTA label assignment in YOLOX?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, computer-vision, yolo

I am confused about how gradient update works for the SimOTA label assignment part in YOLOX.

In Megvii's implementation of the yolo_head.py, there is [get_losses](https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX/blob/main/yolox/models/yolo_head.py) function.

A part of the function calls `get_assignments` function, which implements the SimOTA label assignment strategy mentioned in the original [YOLOX paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.08430.pdf):

```
try:
                (
                    gt_matched_classes,
                    fg_mask,
                    pred_ious_this_matching,
                    matched_gt_inds,
                    num_fg_img,
                ) = self.get_assignments(  # noqa
                    batch_idx,
                    num_gt,
                    total_num_anchors,
                    gt_bboxes_per_image,
                    gt_classes,
                    bboxes_preds_per_image,
                    expanded_strides,
                    x_shifts,
                    y_shifts,
                    cls_preds,
                    bbox_preds,
                    obj_preds,
                    labels,
                    imgs,
                )
```

My understanding is:

1. The `get_assignments` [function](https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX/blob/74b637b494ad6a968c8bc8afec5ccdd7ca6b544f/yolox/models/yolo_head.py#L429) has the `@torch.no_grad()` decorator which would prevent the gradient calculation from taking place in this function during back propagation.
2. (I believe) This would mean that the return values of the `get_assignments` function would be treated as pre-computed constants, except that they will be varying for each image & groundtruth input.
3. Above points suggest that the neural network would be trying to learn something from an (paradoxically) ever-changing pre-computed "constants" for every image input which does not seem to make much sense. Intuition leads me to think that whatever calculation( that could vary across inputs) that results in a loss should be differentiable & BP'ed.

Is there something inaccurate in my understanding of the YOLOX architecture / how BP works?

Answer (score 0):

Upon thinking over my question, I realized that the matching cost matrix obtained from dynamic_k_matching() (inside get_assignments) serves merely as another proxy groundtruth target. There is no reason to compute gradients within a function that creates a target groundtruth.